# SCons: Link a target to a SConscript

Tags: target, scons

I am a bit confused with the functionnement of targets with **SCons**. I am currently trying to create a simple target `check` to launch the `Boost.Test` suite located in my `tests` folder. In order to launch all the tests, I have a `tests/SConscript` file in which I register my cpp files containing my tests by simply calling the `Program` method.

I would simply like to tell **SCons** that he needs to call the `tests/SConscript` file if the target `check` is requested, otherwise, simply build the program by calling `src/SConscript`

```
$> scons check
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in your answer, you can use the SCons Alias() function to assign a name to one or several targets, but this does not tell SCons when to build the targets if you simply execute `scons` without specifying targets. When you dont specify any targets, you'll notice that the unit tests will be built and/or executed.

To tell SCons what should be built, you can use the [SCons Default() function](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.2.0/HTML/scons-user/x2810.html#AEN2829). When you dont use this function, every target will be built by default: obviously only those targets that need to be built, according to the dependencies, etc.

To only build the targets in your `src/SConscript` by default, then assuming its a library, you can do the following:

```
libTarget = env.Library('yourLib', theSourceFiles)
env.Default(libTarget)
```

You can use the Default() function for several different targets.

Now when you execute `scons` without any targets, only those targets set with the Default() function will be built. And if you execute `scons check`, then the check target and its dependencies will be built (assuming you called Alias() with the check target and havent also called Default() with the check target)

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot! I was not finding where this issue was comming from. It's working fine now

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question. From what I saw, you can use Aliases in SCons to bind a **Builder** to a `rule`.

I've read a post from Chris Foster at this address: http://www.scons.org/wiki/UnitTests coming up with the following idea:

For each test we want to add, we add it to the `check` target like this:

```
prog = env.Program(...)
env.Alias('check', prog)
env.Alias(nameOfTheTest, prog)
```

This way, I can call my test in two different ways:

```
$> scons check             # Calls all the tests of the suite
$> scons nameOfTheTest     # Only calls the test we added
```

Hope that helps. Thanks

Comment: This will work when specifying the targets to build, but the problem is that these targets will also get built if you dont specify a target. That is, just executing "scons" will cause these targets to be built, which is something you said you dont want. I added an answer explaining how to get your desired behavior.